# Standard function spaces with the approximation property

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, approximation-theory

A Banach space $\mathcal{X}$ is said to have the approximation property (AP) if, for every compact set $K \subset \mathcal{X}$, there is a sequence of finite rank operators $\{U_n : \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{X}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that
$$\sup_{f \in K}\|f - U_n f\|_\mathcal{X} \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty.$$
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a bounded, open set. I am wondering how much is known about standard function spaces possessing AP. I am particularly interest in the Lebesgue spaces $L^p(\Omega)$ for $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, the Sobolev spaces $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, the uniformly continous functions $C^k(\bar{\Omega})$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$, and maybe even the Besov and Holder spaces, but the previous three are the main ones. The best I could find is [this](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/105403/CommentatMathUnivCarol_013-1972-1_13.pdf) which says that $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ with $1 < p < \infty$ and $\partial \Omega$ is class $C^\infty$ has AP. Or [this](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm41/sm41118.pdf) which explicitly constructs a Schauder basis for $C^k ([0,1]^d)$ and $W^{k,p}([0,1]^d)$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and $1 \leq p < \infty$. What results are known for more general domains?

Comment: Your definition of AP is not quite correct; you should say that the identity is in the closure of the finite rank operators for the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets. That means that there is a net $(U_n)$ such that for each $K$ etc.  Note that all $L_p$ spaces have the AP, even the MAP.

Comment: Do you mean that the sequence $(U)_n$ should not depend on $K$? Isn't the standard definition that, for every compact set $K \subset \mathcal{X}$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there is a finite rank operator $U: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{X}$ such that $\|f - Uf\| \leq \epsilon$ for every $f \in K$ which is essentially what I wrote? My source is Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri "Classical Banach spaces I, II". Also what is your source of the $L^p$ spaces, which $p$(s) does it apply to?

Comment: All $L^p$ spaces have the MAP, as Dirk said. You can deduce this from what is in Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri. Every separable $L^p$ space, $1\le p < \infty$ is isometrically isomorphic to $X \oplus_p Y$, where $X$ is either the zero space or $L^p(0,1)$ and $Y$ is $\ell^p(n)$ with $n = 0,1,...$ or $n=\aleph_0$. All $L^\infty$ spaces are $C(K)$ spaces, so they also have the MAP.

Comment: Your definition of AP is OK but looks strange. I had to look twice to see that it is equivalent to one of the usual definitions (what Dirk wrote or what you wrote in your comment).

Comment: Thanks, the argument for $L^p$ with $1 \leq p < \infty$ makes perfect sense. I don't quite see what you mean by "all $L^\infty$ spaces are $C(K)$ spaces" since $C(\bar{\Omega})$ is separable but $L^\infty (\Omega)$ is not. Any ideas of where to look on the Sobolev spaces? Also thanks for double checking the definition.

Comment: I guess I needed a third look to convince myself that your definition is fine; sorry for stirring confusion!

Comment: As for $C(K)$: The space $L_\infty$ is an abstract $M$-space with unit, hence by Kakutani's representation theorem isometrically isomorphic to a space $C(K)$ with a nonmetrisable compact $K$. (Or use the commutative Gelfand-Naimark theorem). -- Many Besov spaces are isomorphic to $\ell_p$-sums of $\ell_q$'s (and hence have the AP); I don't know what happens when the boundary is non-smooth...

Comment: @NicolaKovachki  For domains $\Omega$ with Lipschitz boundary, the Besov spaces $B^s_{p,q}(\Omega)$ and Triebel-Lizorkin spaces $F^s_{p,q}(\Omega)$  $1\leq p,q<\infty$ possess unconditional bases, e.g., wavelet bases. Sobolev spaces are in the Triebel-Lizorkin, Hölder spaces are in the Besov scale. Any Banach space with a basis have AP. For general domains, please see Triebel's monographs "Theory of Function Spaces I-II-III".

Comment: @NicolaKovachki Another approach to these spaces are through metric measure spaces, which takes on the role of $\Omega$, especially when the boundary is not Lipschitz. Given extra assumptions (e.g., metric being doubling) the smoothness spaces defined on m.m.s. have similar properties to their counterparts on nicer domains.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I think I fully understand the $L^p$ case with $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ (thanks Dirk and Bill!). For $W^{m,p}$ with $1 \leq p < \infty$ as long as the domain is so that there exists a linear extension operator to $\mathbb{R}^d$ (for example, Lipschitz) then there's an isomorphism to $W^{m,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and the existence of unconditional bases implies AP (thanks Onur!). This also holds for all $C^m$ manifolds without boundary $M$ via the isomorphism $W^{m,p}(M) \cong W^{m,p}([0,1]^d)$. The $C^k (\bar{\Omega})$ spaces remain...

Comment: Source for the isomorphisms mentioned above if anyone needs them: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Contribution-to-the-isomorphic-classification-of-Pe%C5%82czy%C5%84ski-Wojciechowski/ee0ef4d0284b2a18f180f2c7d969afefe6f84da1

Comment: Here's a comment on $C^1 [0,1]^2$. Grothendieck, in his 1953 Canad. J. paper claimed that this space is complemented in a $C(K)$-space. A couple of years later, in a short paper in Ann. Inst. Fourier ([Zbl 0072.12003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0072.12003)) he listed all his errors in his work on functional analysis (I think there were four of them), including the above claim, now saying that $C^1 [0,1]^2$ is not complemented in a $C(K)$. If it were, it would inherit the bounded AP from $C(K)$...

Comment: Thank Dirk. The spaces $C^k([0,1]^d)$ have AP since they have Schauder bases as per the paper I posted in the original question. I think, I figured out at least a partial answer for a general domain. Since, to preserve AP, one only needs a vector space isomorphism (not necessarily an isometry), the existence of a $C^k$ homeomorphism between $\bar{\Omega}$ and $[0,1]^d$ is enough to guarantee AP.

Comment: Actually I think you need a $C^k$-diffeomorphism ...